# Creating a Batch File to Rename a File

Tags: batch-file, command-line, file-rename

I am trying to create a batch file (`filehandling.bat`)

I have a file in `C:\Users\username\Downloads` called `"hita_2013_11_05_19_11_38.csv"` where the date/time changes according to the date/time it is created

I need to rename this file to `"hita.csv"`

The problem comes because their will always be an existing `"hita.csv"` file in the directory that needs to remain there unless overwritten with the above file so the REN function isn't working because it is not overwriting the file

I also need it to make no changes(do nothing) to the existing "hita.csv" file if the `"hita_2013_11_05_19_11_38.csv"` file doesn't exist.

I've tried the following commands and can't get any to work: REN, MOV, ROBOCOPY /MOV

I've also tried:

```
IF EXIST "C:\Users\username\Downloads\Hita*.csv" ( 
DEL C:\Users\username\Downloads\Hita.csv 
REN "C:\Users\username\DownloadsHita*.csv" Hita.csv 
) ELSE ( 
Echo The file was not found. 
)
```

but this command still deletes the `"hita.csv"` file for some reason

Comment: The other issue is solved, but instead of `REN` use the `MOVE /y` command and it will overwrite the existing file.

Comment: @foxidrive I ended up using this since it is less code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your test to `IF EXIST "C:\Users\username\Downloads\Hita_*.csv"` (note the underscore before the '*'). The `*` wildcard matches 0 or more characters, so it will match `Hita.csv`, `Hita_01.csv`, or `HitaXYZ.csv`.

Adding the underscore makes it only match files starting with `Hita_` instead.

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much! Sometimes its the SMALLEST things that have your head banging on a desk! lol

Answer (score 0):

Your `hita.csv` matches the wildcard search of `Hita*.csv`, so it will delete it.

I believe you want your wildcard search to be `Hita?*.csv`. The question mark should act as an "exactly one", while the asterisk is "zero or more" characters, which means `Hita.csv` will not match that criteria.

Comment: I thought of this one too, but the poster seems to want a specific format that includes the date combination and underscores; yours would also match `HitaB.csv` or `HitADeer.csv`.

Comment: @KenWhite Yep, I like yours better - I might even go so far as to do `hita_????_??_??_??_??_??.csv` to make it even more explicitly clear what you're attempting to search. And +1 for the `HitADeer` :)